# Python - Are dict types different when it comes to sharing variables across modules (see example)?

Tags: python

I have two files -

foo1.py -

```
a = 0;
b = {};
def f():
    global a;
    print "foo1: start a -",a;
    a = 10;
    print "foo1 changed a to :",a;
    global b;
    print "foo1: start b - ",b;
    b['me'] = 'fool';
    print "foo1 changed b to :",b;
```

foo2.py -

```
from foo1 import *
print "foo2 a before f:", a
print "foo2 b before f:", b
f();
print "foo2 a after f:",a
print "foo2 b after f:",b
```

When I run python foo2.py, I see this -

```
foo2 a before f: 0
foo2 b before f: {} <br/>
foo1: start a - 0
foo1 changed a to : 10
foo1: start b -  {}
foo1 changed b to : {'me': 'fool'}
foo2 a after f: 0 // **Doesn't change**
foo2 b after f: {'me': 'fool'} // **Changes**
```

Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 6):

You think that `a = 10` and `b['me'] = 'fool'` are doing the same kind of thing, but they aren't.  The former binds the name `a` to a new value; the latter mutates the value in `b`.  Assignment to a bare name never modifies objects; it only rebinds names.

When `f` does `a = 10` it rebinds the name `a` to a new object, but this has no effect on `foo2.py`, because `foo2py` has already imported the old object.  When `f` does `b["me"] = "fool"`, it mutates the same dictionary object that was already there.  Since `foo2.py` has imported this same object, it sees the change.

Answer (score 4):

`a` is immutable, so while the reference imported into `foo2` doesn't change, the name in `foo1` is rebound to a new value.

`b` is mutable, and so is never rebound; since both names have the same reference, they are looking at the same object. The same would happen with any mutable object (list, set, etc.).